# Convert MongoDB BsonDocument to valid JSON in C#

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bsondocument

I am working with the MongoDB C# driver. I have a `BsonDocument` with some data which includes some MongoDB-specific types (like ObjectIDs and ISODates). I want to convert this to a valid general-purpose JSON string. In other words, I can't have something like `_id: ObjectId(...)` or `date: ISODate(...)` but would prefer `_id: "..."` and `date: "..."`. Basically, I want to convert these special types that only MongoDB recognizes to regular strings so they can be parsed more easily. The problem is that a built-in function like `.ToJson()` (which another StackOverflow answer suggests) doesn't really convert the document to valid JSON at all because it maintains these special types. My document also contains many levels of arrays and sub-documents, so a simple for loop will not suffice. What's the best way to convert a `BsonDocument` that avoids this problem? I would prefer something built-in rather than manually recursing through the document to fix all the issues.

Comment: I know right. Why would a method called `ToJson()`  return something that is NOT standard Json.. So annoying. Although MarkKGreenway provides a great one liner solution using Newtonsofts API. I think his is the correct answer!

Comment: The best answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788508/2074346

Answer (score 54):

MongoDB.Bson (2.5+) has support to map between BsonValues and .Net objects.
[BsonTypeMapper Class](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonTypeMapper.htm)

**To map a BsonValue (or BsonDocument) to .Net object use**

```
var dotNetObj = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(bsonDoc);
```

You can then use your choice of serialization library. For example,

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotNetObj);
```

**If you have a List of BsonDocument**

```
var dotNetObjList = bsonDocList.ConvertAll(BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue);
```

Comment: This answer is exactly on point.  The issue here is converting the BSON document into an object that map's to DotNet.

Comment: This was the answer.  I have made numerous attempts at a solution to this issue that manifested in a few different ways, from the id to datetime types and this converts into Dot Net, and thus JSON the way you would expect. Excellent work, thank you.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this is not comprehensive.  A good chunk of the types will simply pass through unmapped.  This one bit me when I was trying to map a regular expression to its pattern string.  Had to do it manually.  
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/3c2ddae9d5f0840a9723e723fba58598a59b0791/src/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/BsonTypeMapper.cs#L426

Answer (score 22):

I've ran into the same thing, you can get valid JSON via:

```
var jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict };
JObject json = JObject.Parse(postBsonDoc.ToJson<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(jsonWriterSettings));
```

However it will return something like:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"559843798f9e1d0fe895c831"}, "DatePosted":{"$date":1436107641138}}
```

I'm still trying to find a way to flatten that.

Comment: did you ever have any luck?

Comment: Troll spotted: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver-jsondotnet/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Integrations.JsonDotNet/Converters/ObjectIdConverter.cs#L100

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis i ended up having to manually define a class to deserialize into. Basically -> deserialize into class using Mongo driver fns, then serialize the object... JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Item>(doc)).

Comment: This is valid JSON.  This is called eJson, or extended JSON.  See https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst

Comment: ```JsonOutputMode.Strict``` is now *obsolete*, replacing by ```JsonOutputMode.RelaxedExtendedJson```  worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the best option is to use `Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonReader`.
Here a complete example:

```
public string ToJson(BsonDocument bson)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            BsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, typeof(BsonDocument), bson);
        }
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var reader = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonReader(stream))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            using (var jWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jWriter.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                jWriter.WriteToken(reader);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that this should handle all cases correctly (dates, ids, ...).

Comment: Each line here is a potential bug.. MarkKGreenway provided a mega simple e one liner works as expected!

Comment: @ppumkin If I remember correctly `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` will not correctly handle Guid or some other data types (datetime maybe ...). But I can be wrong ...

Comment: Yes!  I finally found something that works for me.  Note that I had to add some using statements for MongoDB.Bson.IO (for the BsonBinaryWriter) and MongoDB.Bson.Serialization (for the BsonSerializer). I get a warning that Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonReader has moved to its own package (Newtonsoft.Json.Bson), but I have included that package so I don't know why it is complaining.

Comment: I also used a similar method to convert a BsonValue to JSON.

Answer (score 10):

Through experimentation I discovered that there is an option that makes this method output proper JSON:

```cs
BsonDocument myBsonDocument = ... //code that loads a BSON document
myBsonDocument.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.RelaxedExtendedJson})
```

Result:

```json
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5fb7a33e73152101d6610e9d" }, "moreProperties" : "moreValues" }
```

Comment: Shame on MongoDB programmers for not making this the default output!

Comment: It's not the default because certain type information is lost when using `RelaxedExtendedJson`. Which is fine for most use cases, but not all.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the Time for this I use, [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Most of the time that does the trick.  If need be you can set some **JsonSerializerSettings**

Comment: Thank you! This should be the answer! --  I needed that for a customer BsonDocumentJson deserialiser i put in, which used the BsonDocument.ToJson() but returned crap like `NumberDecimal("99.98")` - I just replaced that with your line. Works great!!

Comment: The best answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788508/2074346

Comment: I get an error with the message: "Specified cast is not valid" so this option is not working for me for some reason.  Since this answer was back in 2014, I suspect something has changed in MongoDB or in Json.Net (now Newtonsoft).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way i did it, to skip mongodb _id entry.

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

var result = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument())
     .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id"))
     .ToListAsync();
var obj = result.ToJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the BSON document is saved as, below

```
{
"Date" : "2019-04-05T07:07:31.979Z",
"BSONCONTENT" : {
    "_t" : "MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson",
    "_v" : {
        "A" : "XXXX",
        "B" : 234   
           }  
 }
```

}

then it works with generic class.

```
private static T ProcessBsonConversion<T>(BsonDocument data)
    {
        var content = data.GetElement("_v");
        var jsonDataContent= content.Value.AsBsonValue.ToJson();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonDataContent);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem had to do with how DotNet Core WebAPI serializes an object to json.  If you return a string from a method that is formatted as json, WEBAPI will serialize it to json again.  This is only needed if you are working with a generic BsonDocument to save to MongoDb.

```
[HttpGet()]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetAsync()
{
    return Ok(ret.ToJson());
}
```

Fix

```
[HttpGet()]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetAsync()
{
    var doc = await _collection.Find(...).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return Ok(JObject.Parse(doc.ToJson()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [Davide Icardi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209727/davide-icardi) answer is deprecated so:

1. Install [`Newtonsoft.Json.Bson` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson)
2. Replace `BsonReader` with `BsonDataReader`.

Your extension method should be like this:

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace YourNamespaceGoesHere
{
    public static class BsonHelpers
    {
        public static string ToNormalJson(BsonDocument bson)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                    BsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, typeof(BsonDocument), bson);
                }
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                
                using (var reader = new BsonDataReader(stream))
                {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
                    using (var jWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        jWriter.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                        jWriter.WriteToken(reader);
                    }
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This should generate the expected normal valid JSON string you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this ASP.NET Core for when you may be returning  a model that has BsonDocument to be able to add dynamic data. You can use this JsonConverter implementation based on MarkKGreenway's answer!

```
 public class BsonDocumentJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(BsonDocument);
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            //string json = (value as BsonDocument).ToJson(); //!NB: this returns BSON not JSON. Why on earth is it called ToJson!?
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            writer.WriteRawValue(json);
        }
    }
```

Then in your `Startup.cs` just add the following.

```
  services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new BsonDocumentJsonConverter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
String json = result.toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().objectIdConverter(new Converter<ObjectId>() {
            @Override
            public void convert(ObjectId value, StrictJsonWriter writer) {
                writer.writeString(value.toHexString());
            }
        }).build());
```