# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' in Xunit Test Class

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

I am getting the follwing error in my Xunit test class.

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'.
```

The following way the code is returning the data

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Reg")]
    public async Task <dynamic> User([FromBody] object value)
    {
        //User Registeration
       // To Get All Data
        JObject ReturnData = new JObject();
        try
        {
            var Collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollectio");
            var doc = await Collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

            if(doc != null)
            {

                    // Data.Add("userid",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc));
                    ReturnData.Add("success",1);
                    ReturnData.Add("message","Data Successfully Inserted");
                    ReturnData.Add("data",doc.ToJson());
            }
            else
            {
                ReturnData.Add("success",0);
                ReturnData.Add("message","No Data Found");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            ReturnData.Add("success",0);
            ReturnData.Add("message","Error");
        }
        return ReturnData;
    }
```

Test Class

```
    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
        JObject jObject = new JObject();
        jObject.Add("name", "Satheesh");
        jObject.Add("email", "sat@sat.com");

        JObject finaljObject = new JObject();
        finaljObject.Add("data", finaljObject);

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finaljObject);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/api/Values/Reg", stringContent);

        var t =  response;

        // Assert
        // response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Contains("Data Successfully Retrived", responseString);
    }
```

The actual code is working without any error. When i try to run the test calls it show the error in my actual project.How can i solve it.

Thank you...

Comment: Without source code sample this could be anything.

Comment: What is the type of "doc"?

Comment: doc type is List<BsonDocument>

Comment: You can try like this doc.ToJson().ToString()
This article maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132968/convert-mongodb-bsondocument-to-valid-json-in-c-sharp

Comment: its not working for me getting same error

Comment: Why you receive a parameter of `[FromBody] object value` but never use it ?