# How to retrieve data in proper JSON format from MongoDB in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, angular, mongodb

**I want to retrieve all the documents of a collection from mongoDB in C# .Net Web API. Below code is working fine but It is returning BsonDocument**

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("STRDB");
var mongoCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);
var documents = mongoCollection.AsQueryable();
return Ok(documents);
```

**From above code I am getting data in below format (After JSON.stringify() in angular)**

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "name":"_id",
         "value":"5de9f351baca28556c6a4b71"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Name",
         "value":"Harsha"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Age",
         "value":20
      },
      {  
         "name":"Gender",
         "value":"M"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Skills",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "name":"Java",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "name":"Mule",
               "value":true
            },
            {  
               "name":"Angular",
               "value":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "name":"_id",
         "value":"5de9f358baca28556c6a4b72"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Name",
         "value":"Anji"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Age",
         "value":21
      },
      {  
         "name":"Gender",
         "value":"M"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Skills",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "name":"Java",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "name":"Mule",
               "value":true
            },
            {  
               "name":"Angular",
               "value":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
]
```

How to receive it in proper JSON format OR how to convert this BSON document in JSON as I am unable to process this output.

Comment: Hi Abhi, Have you checked this answer-> https://stackoverflow.com/q/27132968
This might be helpful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, with conversion.

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("STRDB");
var mongoCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);
var documents = mongoCollection.AsQueryable();
return Ok(documents.ToList().ConvertAll(BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue));
```

Comment: documents.ConvertAll() showing error. IMongoQueryable<BsonDocument> does not contain a definition for 'ConvertAll' and no accessible extension method 'ConvertAll' accepting a first argument of type.....

Comment: Try to convert to list first.