# How to write a Generic ASP.NET Core ApiController to do MongoDB CRUD operations from Client Side?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver, generic-programming, webapi

How to write a Generic ASP.NET Core ApiController to do MongoDB CRUD operations from Client Side Frameworks like Angular/React.

Note : Firebase offer such client side library for firestore and database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a request payload definition that would contain an object (or collection) name, operation (`Insert`, `Replace`, `Delete` or any other that you want to support) and the object itself. Inject mongo database object into controller, get a collection by name and apply the operation. Pseudo code may look like this:

```
class Operation
{
    OperationType Type {get; set;}
    JObject Object {get; set;}
    string ObjectId {get; set;}
    string ObjectName {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Apply(Operation operation)
{
    WriteModel<BsonDocument> model = null;

    switch (operation.Type)
    {
        case OperationType.Insert:
            model = new InsertOneModel(ConvertToBsonDocument(operation.Object));
            break;
        case OperationType.Replace:
            model = new ReplaceOneModel(operation.ObjectId, ConvertToBsonDocument(operation.Object));
            break;
        case OperationType.Delete:
            model = new DeleteOneModel(operation.ObjectId);
            break;
    }

    await mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(operation.ObjectName).BultWriteAsync(new[] {model});

    return Ok();
}
```

Or, to make operations to aligned with http spec and for better separation, you can split the logic across multiple actions:

```
[HttpGet("{name}/{objectId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name, string objectId)
{
    var document = await mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(name).Find(new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse(objectId))).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var dotNetObj = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(document);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotNetObj);

    return document is null
        ? NotFound()
        : (IActionResult)Content(json, "application/json");
}


[HttpPost("{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string name, JsonElement @object)
{
    await mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(name).InsertOneAsync(ConvertToBsonDocument(operation.Object));
    return Ok();
}

[HttpPut("{name}/{objectId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string name, string objectId, JsonElement @object)
{
    await mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(name).ReplaceOneAsync(new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse(objectId), ConvertToBsonDocument(operation.Object));
    return Ok();
}

[HttpDelete("{name}/{objectId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string name, string objectId)
{
    await mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(name).DeleteOneAsync(new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse(objectId));
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I tried [HttpGet("{resource}")] , [HttpGet("{resource}/{id?}")] to getall and getbyid and tried to return BsonDocument but getting a parsing error

Comment: I implied `Newtonsoft.Json`, I should've mentioned that explicitly. You can also consider `JsonDocument` instead.

Comment: CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE works perfectly, expect READ. am still struggling.

Comment: @KishoreSahasranaman I've update my answer to support simple get by id request. You could also support some filtering and translate the into mongo query filter, though that will be a bit more advanced logic and will depend on requirements.

Comment: Required to added ToList() to make it work. otherwise all good!!

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I've updated the answer with `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` to make it more correct.

Comment: I tried to use fetch from client side to [HttpGet("{name}/{objectId}")]
But getting an error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 10".

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like built-in json converter doesn't provide valid json. Try Newtonsoft.Json instead as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27136280/2138959.

Comment: This was the perfect answer to solve the invalid JSON issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788508/2074346. Also updated the answer.