# Parse 24-char hex value in json string as BsonObjectId

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, .net-5, bson

I am trying to implement the following flow in a .NET5 Web API (rest endpoint).

1. Receive mongodb query as json string
2. Convert json string to BsonDocument
3. Use BsonDocument to query MongoDb collection

This works great as long as I do not have ObjectIds (and I guess dates) in my json query document.

Following examples

Example1

```
{
  "studentId": "5fd627c58583b9001270e94c"
}
```

Example 2

```
{
  "$or": [
      { "cityId": "5fcf975f1749910011c194f9" },
      { "regionId": "60be5a367eeac21aebefdec4" }
   ]
}
```

Obviously studentId is an ObjectId, unfortunately `BsonDocument.Parse(json);` or `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);` convert that ObjectId into BsonString instead of BsonObjectId.

Can someone point me into the right direction on how to achieve the auto-mapping?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132968/convert-mongodb-bsondocument-to-valid-json-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks @ChinmayT, but that wont work for my case. I have extended the example in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess regex is your only friend here

```
var json = @"
{
    $or: [
        { cityId: ""5fcf975f1749910011c194f9"" },
        { regionId: ""60be5a367eeac21aebefdec4"" }
    ]
}";

json = Regex.Replace(
    json,
    "\"[a-f\\d]{24}\"",
    m => $"ObjectId({m.Value})");

BsonDocument query = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that wont work. I have added another example to give a better idea about the structure that is used for the query.