# Mongo C# driver Deserialize json with NumberDecimal throw Invalid BsonType

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The Deserialize method will fail if the json includes a NumberDecimal value, e.g.:

```
string json = "{  \"newInProducts\" : [{\"planedStockinQty\" : NumberDecimal(\"22\") }] }";
var obj = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(json); // throw an BsonInternalException("Invalid BsonType.")
```

As I can see the reason is there's no Decimal128 case in SkipValue method of [JsonReader.cs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/2c1fb53c443cd91454d1e3cf0f74c3c9b8854332/src/MongoDB.Bson/IO/JsonReader.cs#L780)

I checked the [JsonReader](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/json/JsonReader.java#L417) of the java driver which does have the Decimal128 case.

Is this a bug of the csharp driver ? Any workaround?

Comment: I would suggest to deserialize to `BsonDocument` type or to the class (create according to JSON structure)?

Comment: Above is just for the demo purpose, but there're some situation that can't use `BsonDocument`.

Comment: If it presents in java driver, I would recommend creating a Jira report here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP

Comment: Since you have asked for workarounds as well - check my answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132968/convert-mongodb-bsondocument-to-valid-json-in-c-sharp/55788508#55788508